# Why can´t I access the request.query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

this is my first post so bare with me please.

We are currently working on our first Web-Project and have our problems finding the issues within our project. The project we are working on is a simple website for students to see which groups and modules they have joined. One example for a page is the group-overview which display one group with its members and some other data. The content of the member-table should be filled dynamically based on the group you currently selected. We tried to get this information within the function to fill the table by simply calling "request.query" but the received object is empty.

I´ll leave the code below. Sorry in advance if I have missed any necessary information - feel free to contact me.

**Client-Side Fetch:**

```
fetch('/getStudentsIntoTable')
    .then (response => 
    {
        console.log(response);
        return response.text();
    }).then (text =>
    {
        document.getElementById("tableStudentGroup").innerHTML = text; 
    })
```

**Server-Side Get-Request:**

```
app.get("/getStudentsIntoTable", (request, response, next) => {
    console.log(request.query); <!-- This hands back "{}" -->
    let userID = request.session.userId;
    let abfrage = "SELECT * FROM User ORDER BY 'Nachname'";
    connection.query(abfrage, function(err, result, fields)
    {
        if (err) response.send("Es konnten keine Daten abgerufen werden.");
        if (result != null)
        {
            var resultString = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
            {
                resultString += "<tr><td>" + result[i].User_ID + "</td>" + "<td>" + result[i].Vorname + " " + result[i].Nachname + "</td>" + "<td>" + result[i].E_Mail + "</td></tr>";
            }
            response.send(resultString);
        }
    });
});
```

The URL Looks like this:
"http://localhost:3000/Gruppe/?Gravelshipping++"

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular the part about not posting pictures of text.

Comment: @ikhvjs — That isn't going to have any effect on what the *server-side* code outputs with *console.log*.

Comment: Did you get the ```response``` from fetch?

Comment: @ikhvjs Yes. The response contains the resultString. The only thing thats not working is accessing the request.query.

Comment: Do you want to use the *page* querystring (ie, ?Gravelshipping++) for your *fetch* request?  `fetch ('/getStudentsIntoTable' + window.location.search)...`

Comment: tip: dont build dom serverside, return json and do it clientside, change then you don't need getStudentsIntoTable, just `/students?order=Nachname`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for the Input! I will have a look into it.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of a query string is a `?` followed by a series of `key=value` pairs, separated by `&` characters (and with the `key`s and `value`s URL encoded).

For example:

```
?name1=value1&name2=value2
```

Your URL doesn't follow that format.

Comment: The thing is that the following code works:


`app.get('/Gruppe', (request, response) => {
    console.log(request.query);
    response.sendFile(path.path + '/Gruppe_2_Gruppendefinition/SoSe21/src/Modulgruppenverwaltung/Gruppenansicht.html');
});`

It hands back { 'Gravelshipping++', }
The only difference is, that it wasnt called by fetch().